# Filter an NSArray based on distance from certain point and longitude and latitude

Tags: ios, objective-c, latitude-longitude, coordinate-systems

I have an `entity` with objects in it. These objects have a `longitude` and `latitude`. 
Now what i want to do is the following.

I want all the objects that are `5000 meters` from current location. So now my question is, what is the best way off doing this and keeping in mind that the `entity` can contain up to 5000 records.

I was thinking on making a `NSPredicate` and somehow say that the longitude can have a deviation of  0.005 or something? But I don't have an idea of this is good or bad ?

Comment: depending on a precision you need you might have to use Haversine formula (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) for computing distance between points. But if the distances are small (like 5k meters) computing a deviation in latitude and longitude can be enough.

Comment: Yes but that's the thing. I don't want to manually calculate somehting with a formula and then look if the distance is langer then .. If you have 5000 objects and you need to calculate this 5000 times it is going to take a while.

Comment: That's why you need to keep the distances somewhere. The best algorithms to sort an array have n*log(n) complecity. It means that for 10k objects algorithm need to do about 40k comparisons. If you won't save it you will have to calculate distance between two points about 4 times more than you need to.

Comment: Is your question about filtering an array in memory, or about filtering a Core Data fetch request?

Comment: @MartinR a core data fetch request

Comment: @StefGeelen: You should add that information to the question because it is relevant. You cannot use Objective-C based predicates in a Core Data fetch request or sort descriptor. You can fetch all objects where lat and long are within a certain interval, and then use CoreLocation methods to filter this array in memory. - I am quite sure that this has been answered somewhere before but cannot find it right now.

Comment: The `CLLocation` class has a `distanceFromLocation` method that will compute the distance between two lat/long coordinates. That method can compute 5000 distances in about 3 milliseconds.  Is the core data stored locally on the device, or are you fetching over a network connection?